# match-string in elisp not returning string matched by string-match

Tags: regex, elisp

I have a problem where I fail to get a match-string after a string-match. I think the string-match works, at least it returns non nil, but I get an error when I try to get the match-string. How should I do it?

The failing function:

```
(defun small-test ()
  (string-match "\\([0-9]+\\)-v\\([0-9]+\\).txt" "2011-v9.txt")
  (message (match-string 1))
  )
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From C-h f match-string, I suggest that you read the bottom line:

> (match-string NUM &optional STRING)
>
> Return string of text matched by last
>   search. NUM specifies which
>   parenthesized expression in the last
>   regexp.  Value is nil if NUMth pair
>   didn't match, or there were less than
>   NUM pairs. Zero means the entire text
>   matched by the whole regexp or whole
>   string.
>   **STRING should be given if the last search was by `string-match' on
>   STRING.**

Comment: Thanks, I thought I read that thoroughly, apparently I did not.

Answer (score 1):

```
(defun small-test ()
  (setq matched (string-match"\\([0-9]+\\)-v\\([0-9]+\\).txt" "2011-v9.txt"))
  (message (match-string 1 "2011-v9.txt"))
  )
```

that should work

Comment: That really doesn't make any sense. Why assign `matched`?